# Different color coding and markers on a scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, scatter-plot

I would like to create a `seaborn` scatterplot, using the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [2, 4, 6, 8], 'C':['y', 'y', 'n', 'n'], 'D': [1, 1, 2, 2]})
```

In my graph `A` should be the `x-variable` and `B` the `y-variable`. Furthermore I would like to color based on column `D`. Finally, when `C='y'` the marker should be open-faced (no facecolor) and when `C='n'` the marker should have a closed. My original idea was to use the `hue` and `style` parameter:

```
sns.scatterplot(x='A', y='B', data=df, hue='D', style ='C')
```

However, I did not manage to obtain the graph I am looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One cannot specify entire marker styles (so `'marker'` and `'fillstyle'` keys in your case) for matplotlib yet. Have a look on the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51810492/how-can-i-add-a-list-of-marker-styles-in-matplotlib#51810842).

So the only thing left for you is to use different markers right away and specify them (as list or dictionary)

```py
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='A', y='B', hue='D', style='C', markers=['o', 's'])
plt.show()
```

Apparently, it is very hard to even create non-filled markers in seaborn, as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66404883/seaborn-scatterplot-set-hollow-markers-instead-of-filled-markers) explains. The only option is to do some matplotlib-seaborn-hybrid thing... So if you accept to plot things twice onto the same axis (one for a filled marker and one for the unfilled markers), you still have to dig yourself into the quirks of seaborn...