# How to plot scatter graph with markers based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a scatter graph on some data with grouping. They are grouped by the column `group` and I want them to have different **marker styles** based on the group.

#### Minimal working code

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

colors = ['r','g','b','y']
markers = ['o', '^', 's', 'P']

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["index"] = list(range(100))
df["data"] = np.random.randint(100, size=100)
df["group"] = np.random.randint(4, size=100)
df["color"] = df.apply(lambda x: colors[x["group"]], axis=1)
df["marker"] = df.apply(lambda x: markers[x["group"]], axis=1)

plt.scatter(x=df["index"], y=df["data"], c=df["color"])
# What I thought would have worked
# plt.scatter(x=df["index"], y=df["data"], c=df["color"], marker=df["marker"])
plt.show()
```

[image: example_output]

#### What I want

I want the groups to have different marker styles as well. For example the red entries will have marker "o" (big dot), green entries with marker "^" (upward triangle) and so on.

#### What I tried

I thought

```py
plt.scatter(x=df["index"], y=df["data"], c=df["color"], marker=df["marker"])
```

would have worked but nope...

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

I can `for` loop over the DataFrame and group the entries by their `group`. Then plot them with the `marker` argument set with the list defined (like `plt.scatter(..., marker=markers[group])`. That would result in 4 `plt.scatter(...)` as there are 4 groups in total. But that is ugly IMO to loop through a DataFrame row by row and I strongly believe there is a better way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried to see if various scatter plot markers could be supported in the list, but it still doesn't seem to be possible. The best way is to make it a function, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51810492/how-can-i-add-a-list-of-marker-styles-in-matplotlib).

Comment: As an alternative, if you use Seaborn, the following code will do the trick. `sns.scatterplot(x=df["index"], y=df["data"], c=df["color"],style=df['marker'])`

Comment: @r-beginners Lemme take a look at Seaborn :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### matplotlib

> that is ugly IMO to loop through a DataFrame row by row and I strongly believe there is a better way

With matplotlib, I don't think there is a better way than to loop. Note that if you [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the markers, it does *not* loop row by row, just group by group (so 4 times in this case).

This will call [`plt.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) 4 times (once per marker):

```
for marker, d in df.groupby('marker'):
    plt.scatter(x=d['index'], y=d['data'], c=d['color'], marker=marker, label=marker)
plt.legend()
```

[image]

---

#### seaborn

As r-beginners commented, [`sns.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) supports multiple markers via `style`:

```
sns.scatterplot(x=df['index'], y=df['data'], c=df['color'], style=df['marker'])
```

[image]